# Newsletter sign up page (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, newsletter

I am creating a newsletter sign up page with PHP and MySQL. I use this free source from [**this site**](https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter).

I have created a database in MySQL and has tested successfully and linked it to my PHP files. However, I am getting **error Notice** when I preview it (`subscribe.php`). Not sure what variables I have miss out in the code.

> Notice: Undefined index: signup-email in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\subscribe.php on line 15
>   {"status":"error","message":"The email address field must not be blank"}**

Here is my code (2 PHP files):

**newsletters.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>newsletters</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newsletter.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="newsletterform">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Get Email Update</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ullamcorper sapien luctus nisl laoreet, ac commodo tellus placerat. Etiam nec magna lacus. Curabitur quis felis vel nisl tincidunt hendrerit.</p>
        <form action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
        <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        </form>
        <div id="response"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**subscribe.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>newsletter-submit</title> 
</head>

<body>
<?php

$host   = "localhost";
$dbname = "cc_email_list";
$user   = "ccemail";
$pass   = "password";
$email    = filter_var($_POST['signup-email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

    if (empty($email)) {
        $status = "error";
        $message = "The email address field must not be blank";
    } else if (!preg_match('/^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/', $email)) {
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You must fill the field with a valid email address";
    } else {
        $existingSignup = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM signups WHERE     signup_email_address='$email'");
        $existingSignup->execute();
        $data_exists = ($existingSignup->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;

        if (!$data_exists) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date) VALUES (:email, :datetime)";
            $q = $db->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(
                array(
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':datetime' => $datetime
            ));

            if ($q) {
                $status = "success";
                $message = "You have been successfully subscribed";
            } else {
                $status = "error";
                $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
            }
        } else {
            $status = "error";
            $message = "This email is already subscribed";
        }
    }

    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    $db = null;
}
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try assigning it first `$email_address = $_POST['signup-email'];` then `$email = filter_var($email_address, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);`

Comment: tried added this but the error still the same..: (

Comment: Your present code checks out just as it is (have successfully echo'd email address) make sure you have entered a valid email address. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything and if you're not already using it. Also add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Q: Are you in fact putting anything inside the form's Email input?

Comment: I tried to type in an email address in the preview page and I tried it says "An error occurred, please try again"

Comment: Did you create the table, the columns, etc.? I can't see why you'd be getting any errors/problems. JS exists etc.? Not much else I can suggest.

Comment: Yes, this is the sql code.     CREATE TABLE `signups` (
  `signups_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `signup_email_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signup_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`signups_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Hi Fred, After I key in an email in the newsletter.php, I got the error message, "An error occurred, please try again", but the email address I fill in actually store to the MySQL database. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't know why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

### Why you're facing this problem

This error means $_POST['signup-email'] is not set (so the form was submitted without filling the field with the name "signup-email" or it wasn't filled at all).
This isn't a heavy error and it won't compromise the correct operation of the code.

### Solution

If you want to turn off reporting for this kind of errors, add this code just after the opening of the PHP tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: it still come out error as,
{"status":"error","message":"The email address field must not be blank"}, if I want to amend the code >> $_POST['signup-email'], how should I do it instead of turn of the reporting error?

Comment: @Andy8333 You have to visit newsletters.php and fill the field with name "signup-email",then submit the form: you will be brought to subscribe.php and the error will not be reported

Comment: May I know which specific name in newsletters.php you referring to?

    <form action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
        <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </form>

Comment: <input type="email" *name="signup-email"* id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" /> you have to fill this field :)

Comment: what should I fill in, an email example? I am getting "An error occurred, please try again" when I am filling an email address in newsletter.php preview page.

Comment: @Andy8333 Yes, you should put an email. That error means the query couldn't be executed properly.

Comment: the error still remain even I changed it to <input type="email" name="example@hotmail.com" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />

Comment: @Andy8333 I think I haven't explained properly: the code should be <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />  , but you have to **fill** this input :) i.e. Open newsletters.php, put a random email and submit the form

Comment: I tried also type in an email address in the newsletters.php, it shows "An error occurred, please try again"

Comment: @Andy8333 that means $q couldn't be executed. Check if your credentials for database connection are correct. If they are, var_dump $q and run it through phpMyAdmin: if works, the problem is somewhere else, otherwise it contains an error

Comment: the database connection is fine, I had it tested. But how can I run the var_dump $q in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Put var_dump($q); at the end of your code and copy the query output, then open phpMyAdmin, click on the name of your database chosing from the ones displayed in the left side, then on "SQL"; paste the query, click on "run" and you're done :)

Comment: I just realize, although I got the error message, "An error occurred, please try again", but the email address I fill in actually store to the MySQL database.

Comment: That's really weird. The problem may be in the logic of the code, but it looks fine...

Comment: I'm not familiar with php code, this really suffer me..don't know which part of it went wrong, but it works perfectly in their demo page >> http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/uploads/ajax-newsletter/    and this is their source page >> https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter

Comment: Are you using an obsolete version of PHP?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for Windows, should I change to other software instead?

Comment: @Andy8333 No, XAMPP is ok, you should just check if it's updated :) I tested your code with the latest version of PHP and it works

Comment: I will update my php version and try again later, thks for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you get hung up on 'Notices' you're going to really hate big PHP projects in future :)! Most people just turn them off, which you can do by placing the following code at the top of any php page

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>
```